# Webstorm 10 - Node debbuger on a gulp file doesnt work

Tags: node.js, debugging, gulp

I have a gulpfile and i added some tasks for example: less to compile less files.

I wanted to test one of my functions that ive added to the pipeline and put a breakpoint there and this is how it looks like:
[image]

However when im executing debug on this task, this it the output i receive:
[image]

it never stop at any of the breakpoints above, does anyone have any idea what cause this?

**Webstorm version**: 10.0.4